# Append each dict object from function execution in 'for' loop to new empty dictionary

Tags: python, function, dictionary, for-loop

I have this scenario where I create a dict object within a function and assign it to a global argument. Now I want to append the result of iteration with a for loop (each dict) to one dictionary.

```
def ping_ip(ip)
   ...
   global ip_dict
   ip_dict = {....}
```

Now I'm calling the function this way:

```
if __name__ == "__main__": 
   ip_list = [ip1, ip2, ip3]
   big_ip_dict = {}
   for ip in ip_list:
      ping_ip(ip)
      big_ip_dict |= ip_dict
```

I'm getting only the result from the last ip (ip3), inside the big_ip_dict, obviously there must be something wrong with my for loop logic here. The '|' is for concatenating dictionaries. Any suggestion?

Comment: Why not just `return ip_dict` instead of using a `global`?

Comment: Yes, but still same issue will persist

Comment: Does each instance of `ip_dict` have the same keys?  If so, concatenation is just going to overwrite the previous values of those keys - it's only useful with dicts having *distinct* keys.

Comment: Thanks for reminding that, yes they have the same exact keys. I will try to come up with something else than.